# three table based relation display in yii gridview

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I'm getting foreign key relation based display ids in the gridviews. How to get values instead of ids? Code in my gridview is following:

```
$criteria->compare('education.UniversityNameid',$this->UniversityName, true);
```

my gridviews inside code

```
 array( 
             'name' => 'UniversityName',
             'type' => 'raw',
                'value'=>'(empty($data->education->UniversityNameid))? "" : Yii::app()->params["currencySymbol"]." ".$data->education->UniversityNameid',

       ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up a relation in your model "University" like this

```
public function relations() {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'UniversityName' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'University', 'UniversityNameid'),
        );
    }
```

thank you can access the Name

```
$data->education->UniversityName
```

Comment: foreign key id based only  getting universityid but university table  is different  see my post clearly

Comment: please post more information about the models your where using

Answer (score 0):

Set the relation in your model like

```
'u' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'University', 'UniversityNameid'),
```

and acess it like

```
  'attributes'=>array(

            array('name'=>'u.UniversityName',
            'label'=>'University',),


   ),
```

Comment: Dency G B  but  foreign key id based only getting universityid but university table is different